# Xesmf interpolate to several observational position

Tags: python, python-xarray

Using the Xesmf, we can interpolate gridded reanalysis data into the observational position to make a comparison between reanalysis with in-situ observations.

For example, when we have a SST reanalysis as [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gcGknAtQJIWjYmGiXEgzKdIkhwUg2SLP/view?usp=sharing) and three observational positions like
OBS1: (-46.9, 37.9), OBS2: (-37.8, 77.5), OBS3 (-42.9, 147.3), we can make an interpolation as

```
SST = xr.open_dataarray('./SST.nc')
ds_SST_grid = xr.Dataset({'lat':(['y','x'],SST.lat.values), 
                          'lon':(['y','x'],SST.lon.values)})
ds_OBS_grid = xr.Dataset({'lat':(['y','x'],np.array([-46.9,-37.8,-42.9])[:,np.newaxis]),
                          'lon':(['y','x'],np.array([37.9, 77.5, 147.3])[:,np.newaxis])})
SST_to_OBS = xe.Regridder(ds_SST_grid, ds_OBS_grid, 'bilinear')
SST_in_OBS = SST_to_OBS(SST)
```

Here the shape of the output, i.e., the SST_in_OBS, is `(3,1)`, and squeezing the output gives us the reanalysis values in the observational position.

However, in my mind, the most convenient way is to generate an output with a shape of `(3,)` directly, but I failed after some try.

So, my question is, how to construct the output_grid to get an output with `(3,)` directly instead of `(3,1)`?